# Apps Script: Check if range is empty and copy data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, while-loop, range

I'm trying to build an automated list with google sheets. The first sheet(A) is for input of production data of a week. The second sheet(B) should be the data archive. Thus i want the content from sheet A copied to sheet B and then deleted in sheet a. It should be copied in the next empty range in sheet B.

My problem must be inside the notation of the "while" or / and the "if" but nothing seems to work properly.

The while checks if sheet A is already emptied, if not the "if" function checks a specific range in sheet B if it is empty. If thats the case it should be copying the data and then delete it. Else the column of the range in sheet b is changed to the next range (spaltennummer + 6).

While troubleshooting it either stays in the while (finds no empty range?) or it runs through without any effect. I tried "== 0", "== """, isblank and so on. (every option available?). Google didnt seem able to provide me an answer...

Thanks for ur help.

Code:

```
function myFunction() {}
function leerzelle(){
 
  var spaltennummer = 4;
  var rangeDatenarchiv = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").getRange(8,spaltennummer,15,5);
  var rangeDateneingabe = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dateneingabe").getRange("J8:N22");
  var values = rangeDateneingabe.getValues();

while(rangeDateneingabe !== 0){
 
  if(rangeDatenarchiv == 0) {
    rangeDatenarchiv.setValues(values);
    rangeDateneingabe.setValues("");
  }
  else{
    spaltennummer = spaltennummer + 6;
    
  }
 
}
}
```

Comment: `rangeDateneingabe` is a range not values so it it makes no sense to check it's equivalence to zero. Same is true about `rangeDatenarchiv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

#### Code:

```
function leerzelle() {
  var spaltennummer = 4;
  // Data entry
  var rangeDateneingabe = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dateneingabe").getRange("J8:N22");

  var values = rangeDateneingabe.getValues();
  // While we have value in data entry sheet
  while (!rangeDateneingabe.isBlank()) {
    // Update archive everytime you increment in else
    var rangeDatenarchiv = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").getRange(8, spaltennummer, 15, 5);
    // If archive range is blank, move values
    if (rangeDatenarchiv.isBlank()) {
      rangeDatenarchiv.setValues(values);
      rangeDateneingabe.clearContent();
    }
    else {
      spaltennummer = spaltennummer + 6;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- You just can't compare a range to a number, use `isBlank` to check if it doesn't have values instead.
- You can't use `setValues("")` on a range to remove the contents, use `clearContent` instead to delete those values.
- You need to redeclare archive range everytime you loop using the incremented column number

#### References:

- [isBlank](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isBlank())
- [clearContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent())

Comment: Hey @NaziA,
thanks for your answer. I have tried this already and the isBlank function seems to be bugged a little. It stays in the while even tho there are free ranges. As i stopped the script "spaltennummer" was at 48508 but how can he not find an empty range till then? So the "if" condition just does not get reached and thus the while condition isnt either.
I have also tried in the grid to check if "isBlank" is working properly and i had some varying results. Maybe theres a way to check each number of the array you get from "getValues" but i am not sure how to do that.
Thanks again :)

Comment: Can you please share a sample sheet? since in the sheet I'm working, the code above works, and after moving the data, it stops. @Sammi

Comment: thanks for helping further. I uploaded the file to sendspace but i could only upload it in excel format... hope its ok :)
https://www.sendspace.com/file/2gcq9h

Comment: forgot to mention you in my comment and i read editing comments can result in a deletion of the comment. @NaziA

Comment: Hi @Sammi, you need to redeclare archive range everytime you loop using the incremented column number. I have updated the script in my answer above and that should work on your data.

Comment: Hi @Sammi, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Hey @NaziA, I will be able to check at Monday. Gonna mark it as answer if it works. Thanks again for your kind help, stay healthy and have a nice weekend :)

Comment: works completely as intended! Thank you very much!